# How to install Unix on VM?

Tags: windows-7, installation, unix, virtualbox, parallels

My system is has an AMD Athlon II x2 and I'm trying to install (one of the following?) Red Hat Linux Enterprise for x64 systems, debian for amd64, freebsd 8.1  for amd64 as a VM using Parallels or VBox. During installation (of the VM) it shows an error telling me that my processor arhitecture is i686, but its x64! What is the problem?

My OS is Win7.

VMware doesn`t install on my computer, I don't know why!

Does anyone knows how to install a unix system on a VM?

Comment: Which Athlon is it exactly? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_Athlon_X2_microprocessors has a list. Which version of VMware are you trying to install?

Comment: Please change the title of the question (if possible) to better describe this problem.

Comment: Is your host OS running in 32-bit mode?